# After clicking verification link ,how to redirect mail to Android App

Tags: android, url

After clicking verification link on a mail, how it directly redirect to Android app please explain.

Example :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to use intent filter in the activity which you want to launch on click of URL like this:

```
     <activity
           .
           .
           .

            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.yourdomain.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/path/to/resource" />
            </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

in your case

1. `scheme` will be `https`
2. `host` will be `www.quora.com`
3. `pathPrefix` will be `/signup/confirm_email`

Answer (score 0):

@RAHUL TIWARI

this is Register_PAGE AND i wrote the code same of you...
In activity after clicking submit button, a verfication link will be send to email addresss..
(am stuck in) afer cliking verfication link it must came back to myApp..

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".Register_User">
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="scaano.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/Welcome/userprofile" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

this one is email am getting in mail:

[0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znLUQ.png)